# jquery load content into iframe only on the first button click

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick

I am sure I must be missing something simple on this.

I have a page that has 3 buttons on it named showHome, showRecords, showFinance, I also have 3 divs named divHome, divRecords, divFinance, and inside each of those divs I have 3 iframes named iframeHome, iframeRecords, iframeFinance.

The goal here is to load the first iframe after the page renders, then as the user clicks the next button the next iframe will have its source set dynamically and then the div will be shown so that the users can see the external content, still on my domain, but just somewhere else. Of course the same on the 3rd button click, iframe is passed a url to load and then the div is displayed. Now when the user clicks on one of the other buttons, the div should show or hide, no reason to reload the content.

So I need to keep track of which button was clicked so that if it has a 1 it will just show or hide the div, otherwise the iframe needs to be set. I have had a version of this working, not very elegantly, so I am trying to write this with less code and here is what I have that is not working, I know why but I am not sure how to fix it.

My current script looks like this

```
var showHome_clicked = '1';
var showDataMart_clicked = '0';
var showFinance_clicked = '0';
var showCost_clicked = '0';
var showSchedule_clicked = '0';
var showPerformance_clicked = '0';
var showWinsight_clicked = '0';
var pageToLoad = "http://sp2010/dashboard/0045/default.aspx";

function showRequestedContent(){
    var displayedDiv = $('div.contentDiv').filter(function(){
        if($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
            alert(buttonClicked);
            $('.contentDiv:visible').fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div" + ($(this).index()+1)).show().fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
}


$("input").click(function(e)
{
    var buttonClicked = (e.target.id + '_clicked');
    var targetIframe = (e.target.id).replace("show", "iframe");
/* Here I need to check the variable that i created, but it contains the name of my manipulated value not the 1 or 0 I need to check for, not sure how to do this? */
    if(buttonClicked == '0'){
        $(targetIframe).attr('src',  pageToLoad + '?isdlg=1');
            buttonClicked = '1';
            alert("zero");
            showRequestedContent;
    }
    else if(buttonClicked == '1'){
        showRequestedContent;
        alert("one");
    }

});
```

-------------UPDATED This is now working ---------------

```
var buttonClicked = 'showHome';
var currentDiv = 'divHome';

$('.switchIframe').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.id != buttonClicked){
        targetDiv = (e.target.id).replace("show", "div");
        var $targetIframe = $($(this).data('target')), 
        src = $(this).data('src');
        if($targetIframe.attr('src') != src){
            $targetIframe.attr('src', src);
        }

        showDiv(targetDiv);
        hideDiv(currentDiv);
        currentDiv = targetDiv;
        buttonClicked = e.target.id;
    }

});

function showDiv(id) {
   var $sDiv = $('#' + id);
   $sDiv.show(500);
}

function hideDiv(id) {
   var $hDiv = $('#' + id);
   $hDiv.hide(200);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divHome').show();   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not check if the iframe has a `src` not equal to `'about:blank'`?

```
$('input').click(function(e){
 // your code for targetIframe

  var currentSrc = $(targetIframe).attr('src');
  if(currentSrc == "about:blank"){
    $(targetIframe).attr('src', pageToLoad);
  }
  showRequestedContent(); // <-- In your code you forgot the parenthesis.
});
```

And this assumes your iframes start out:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" id="yourID"></iframe>
```

**EDIT:**

The easiest way to store and retrieve values from DOM nodes is to use `data-*` attributes.

For example:

```
<button class="switchIframe" data-target="#iframe1" data-src="http://youtube.com">Show iframe 1</button>
<iframe src="about:blank" id="iframe1"></iframe>
```

Then your jQuery would look something like:

```
$('.switchIframe').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $targetIframe = $($(this).data('target')),
      src = $(this).data('src');

  // if it's not the same source, load it.
  if($targetIframe.attr('src') != src){
    $targetIframe.attr('src', src);
  }

  showRequestedContent();
});
```

Comment: looks like that will work I still have the same issue however, I can't seem to figure out a way to dynamically set the targetIframe varible, I keep getting an undefined error due to the value of targetIframe being "iframeHome" <-- a string value. I was expecting that when I created the targetIframe variable that I would be able to set the actual targeted iframe, this is the same issue I was having trying to set the buttonClicked_clicked variable, I was getting a string value, which is correct, but that is not what I needed to do. Otherwise this appears to work great!

Comment: Thank you for that update, I am still trying to wrap my head around how this works. What I found that helped me was to pass my dynamically created variables into a function in order to make this work. Thank you for your help. This is what I have now

Answer (score 0):

Why did you need jQuery for that?

```
<a href="/pages/page1.htm" target="content">Page 1</a>
| <a href="/pages/page2.htm" target="content">Page 2</a>
| <a href="/pages/page3.htm" target="content">Page 3</a>
| <a href="#" id="end">End</a>

<iframe id="frame1" name="content" src="/pages/page1.htm"/>
```

Since you are loading those pages into the iframe, those visits will be recorded into your web stats anyway

As for show/hide:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#end').on('click',function(){
  $('#frame1').hide();
});
</script>
```

If you want to show the frame again after hiding, by clicking one of the links (Page 1, Page 2, etc.), then throw your links into a ul element and add the functionality to the list items you want it to work for within that list, e.g.

```
<ul id="links">
  <li><a class="link" href="/pages/page1.htm" target="content">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="/pages/page2.htm" target="content">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="/pages/page3.htm" target="content">Page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="end">End</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#links a.link').on('click',function() {
  if (!$('#frame1').is(":visible")) $('#frame1').show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I need to retain the content loaded into the iframe, or if the content has not yet been requested, when the user clicks the button the first time it will load up into the iframe. Any time the user clicks a button they already clicked we want to show or hide the div, so they don't have to wait for the iframe to load again. So I need to either have the same amount of iframes as buttons or dynamically create them on the fly, I also need a way to dynamically target the current visible div, so I can hide or show it when a user clicks the button.